# error: "select configuration element in the tree to edit its settings"

Tags: android-studio

I open my project, android studio call:" granle sync failed". Then I download new grandle file and go to "Project Structure" but it doesn't show anything with one line:  "select configuration element in the tree to edit its settings".

Answer (score 2):

FWIW, I ran into this same issue (with Android Studio Giraffe, 2022.3.1 Beta 1, mind you) and solved it with an IDE restart.

Answer (score 0):

I've got the same issue, my solution was - File-> Menage IDE settings -> Restore default settings, Than reasore and restart: It will restart IDE with default settings and I find out that live settings works but soon as I install flutter plugins problem appeared again - maybe because I have install couple plugins whithout restart IDE -  so I repeat reset process and when install flutter plugin again I restart IDE soon after first flutter plugin was instaled - now it works - maybe this will help - good luck ;)